# Python sum() is calculating same value for two different lists

Tags: python, list, math, technical-indicator

I'm trying to do technical analysis using RSI which involves having 2 lists of gains and losses then getting the average of the 2 lists. For some reason, when using sum(), I receive the same value for the 2 lists. When manually adding the sum of the lists I see different results. This is what I have:

```
def calculate_avg_gain(in_list : list) -> tuple:
gain_list = []
loss_list = []
for i, close in enumerate(in_list):
    try:
        change = close - in_list[i-1]
    except IndexError:
        change = 0.0
    if change >= 0.0:
        gain_list.append(change)
        loss_list.append(0.0)
    else:
        gain_list.append(0.0)
        loss_list.append(abs(change))
avg_gain = sum(gain_list) / 14
avg_loss = sum(loss_list) / 14
return avg_gain, avg_loss
```

I stepped in the code when I had 14 entries for each:

```
gain_list = [1.1800000000000068, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10000000000002274, 0.0, 0.44999999999998863, 0.030000000000001137, 0.0, 0.160000000000025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15000000000000568, 0.0, 0.05000000000001137]
loss_list = [0.0, 0.19999999999998863, 0.10999999999998522, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.3299999999999841, 0.0, 0.47999999999998977, 0.0, 0.10000000000002274, 0.25, 0.0]

avg_gain = 0.15142857142857583
avg_loss = 0.1407142857142836
```

The sum for both comes out to 2.12, which is what I get for the sum of loss_list, while I get 2.1799 for gain_list. Am I missing something?

Comment: I calculated ~1.969

Comment: They both sum to 1.97.  Perhaps your data isn't what you expect.

Comment: I'll update it to a different timeframe that had differing values. This was a bad example.

Comment: You're miscalculating the lists. Notice how in your first iteration in the for loop, you access the first item and the item in index -1.

Comment: what code did you use to find the sum of both (which came out as 2.12)?

Comment: I did sum(gain_list) and sum(loss_list). The answer below by @reddynishant explains what the problem was -- it was never throwing the IndexError that I thought it would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the problem here is that, whenever you do `in_list[-1]` it will not throw `IndexError`, but it will use the last element that is `in_list[len(list)-1]`

```py
In [4]: def calculate_avg_gain(in_list : list) -> tuple:
   ...:     gain_list = []
   ...:     loss_list = []
   ...:     for i, close in enumerate(in_list):
   ...:         try:
   ...:             change = close - in_list[i-1]
   ...:         except IndexError:
   ...:             change = 0.0
   ...:         if change >= 0.0:
   ...:             gain_list.append(change)
   ...:             loss_list.append(0.0)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             gain_list.append(0.0)
   ...:             loss_list.append(abs(change))
   ...:         print(gain_list, loss_list, change)
   ...:     avg_gain = sum(gain_list) / 14
   ...:     avg_loss = sum(loss_list) / 14
   ...:     return avg_gain, avg_loss
   ...:

In [5]: calculate_avg_gain(a)
[0.0] [4] -4
[0.0, 1] [4, 0.0] 1
[0.0, 1, 1] [4, 0.0, 0.0] 1
[0.0, 1, 1, 1] [4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 1
[0.0, 1, 1, 1, 1] [4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 1
Out[5]: (0.2857142857142857, 0.2857142857142857)
```

You can update the code to the following:

```py
In [6]: def calculate_avg_gain(in_list : list) -> tuple:
   ...:     gain_list = []
   ...:     loss_list = []
   ...:     for i, close in enumerate(in_list):
   ...:         if i == 0:
   ...:             continue
   ...:         change = close - in_list[i-1]
   ...:         if change >= 0.0:
   ...:             gain_list.append(change)
   ...:             loss_list.append(0.0)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             gain_list.append(0.0)
   ...:             loss_list.append(abs(change))
   ...:         print(gain_list, loss_list, change)
   ...:     avg_gain = sum(gain_list) / 14
   ...:     avg_loss = sum(loss_list) / 14
   ...:     return avg_gain, avg_loss
   ...:

In [7]: calculate_avg_gain(a)
[1] [0.0] 1
[1, 1] [0.0, 0.0] 1
[1, 1, 1] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 1
[1, 1, 1, 1] [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 1
Out[7]: (0.2857142857142857, 0.0)
```

If you want a one-liner for change, you can do the following

```py
>>> [j-i for i, j in zip(t[:-1], t[1:])]
[2, 3]
```

Then if change is > 0, you can add to gain, if not to loss.

Other ways:

```py
for i in range(1, len(in_list)):
    change = in_list[i] - in_list[i-1]
```

if you are already using `NumPy` in your project, you can do

```py
import numpy as np
in_list = np.array([5, 4, 89, 12, 32, 45])
  
  
# Calculating difference list
diff_list = np.diff(in_list)
```

Comment: Could also change the `for` signature to: `for i, close in enumerate(in_list[1:]):` in order to not run over the first item

Comment: I think the OP intended to loop around to the back of the list. The 14-element list represents a 14-day cycle where the last element can be considered to come just before the first.

Comment: @Adid If you do `for i, close in enumerate(in_list[1:]):`, `i` will still be running from `0`

Comment: @reddynishanth You can in turn change `change = close - in_list[i-1]` to `change = close - in_list[i]` to solve that too, and then you also get the correct result.

Comment: @Adid We can do that, but I feel this is much better `[j-i for i, j in zip(t[:-1], t[1:])]`

Comment: I agree that it's more *pythonic* but it's less readable for people who are unsure what `zip` does.

Comment: For readability, I would probably do `for i in range(1, len(in_list)): change = in_list[i] - in_list[i-1]`, this is easily readable

Comment: I'm still a beginner in python, I had to look up how to use zip. This is a personal project so as long as I can read/understand it, I'd be okay with using the pythonic way.
It seems like the original solution works!

Comment: @DeepShah I've added other ways which you can use, take a look

Comment: @reddynishanth thank you! I'm not using NumPy yet but I might have to start, this is the second time I've seen it and liked the implementation.

Comment: For daily use, you don't need `NumPy`, it is mostly used for scientific computing. I've been using Python for over 3 years and never used `NumPy`.